# Neuralnet Unexpected prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to understand how the package neuralnet works.

I am using the mnist dataset, which contains 60.000 rows that correspond to different pictures and 785 columns that represent each pixel of the pictures (except for the first
column that corresponds to the label of the picture).

```
initial_data <- read.csv(file = 'train.csv', header = TRUE)
```

The data looks like this:

```
    label pixel1 pixel2 pixel3 pixel4 pixel5 pixel6 ...
1     5      0      0      3      0      1      0   ...
2     3      0      0      0      7      0      0   ...
etc
```

First I remove the pixels that have a variance equal to 0. Since they are not informative to assess which is the number written in the picture.

```
filtered_data <- initial_data %>%
  select_if(function(col) var(col) != 0)

# Show dimension of the new filtered data
dim(filtered_data)
```

Then I standardize the data to ensure that each feature contributes equally
to the model, and the algorithm is not influenced by features with larger scales.

```
filtered_data <- as.data.frame(scale(filtered_data[-1]))
```

Now I make the data partition (80% training and 20% test).

```
filtered_data$label <- initial_data$label
filtered_data <- filtered_data %>% select(label, everything())
index <- createDataPartition(filtered_data$label, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)

# Create training and validation sets
training_data <- filtered_data[index, ]
validation_data <- filtered_data[-index, ]

# Separate by predictors and labels
training_data_X <- training_data[-1]
training_data_Y <- training_data[1]
validation_data_X <- validation_data[-1]
validation_data_Y <- validation_data[1]
```

Now I generate a very simple neural network and make the predictions

```
input_variables <- paste(names(training_data_X), collapse = " + ")
output_variable <- names(training_data_Y)[1]  
content_formula <- paste(output_variable, "~", input_variables)

simple_nn_model <- neuralnet(content_formula, data = training_data, hidden = 1, 
                             act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE)

predictions_simple_model <- predict(simple_nn_model, newdata = validation_data_X)
```

**Issue:** I would expect that the object predictions_simple_model contains 10 columns (each column represents one number between 0 and 9) and their values should range from 0 to 1 (depending on the prediction made by the model). But, instead, I obtain a single column and all of their values are equal to 1.

```
> predictions_simple_model
           [,1]
137   1.0000000
171   1.0000000
213   1.0000000
225   1.0000000
236   1.0000000
420   1.0000000
576   1.0000000
615   1.0000000
899   1.0000000
etc
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: you need to create a dummy matrix for the output, and then using this create a 10 variable string for the left hand side of your formula

Comment: @user20650 Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

For multiclass outputs, either a binary matrix representation of the labels can be passed, or (easier) convert the labels to a `factor` and let `neralnet` do it for you. There are examples of both in `?neuralnet` and `?predict.nn`.

An example of each for the `mnist` data in your question.

First get the data

```
library(dslabs) # for the data
library(neuralnet)
# mnist data
mnist <- read_mnist()

# training data
train <- data.frame(y=mnist$train$labels, mnist$train$images)
```

- Using a factor variable:

```
# coerce the labels to a factor to allow the easy calculation of a
# dummy matrix representation within the formula
train$y <- as.factor(train$y)

set.seed(1)
mod <- neuralnet(y ~ ., data = train[1:100,], hidden = 2, 
                             act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE)

# generate predictions on each label
pred <- predict(mod, newdata=mnist$test$images)
head(round(pred, 3))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
# [1,] 0.144 0.154 0.066 0.121 0.112 0.055 0.022 0.110 0.088 0.120
# [2,] 0.144 0.154 0.066 0.121 0.112 0.055 0.022 0.110 0.088 0.120
# [3,] 0.034 0.037 0.015 0.037 0.004 0.016 0.994 0.023 0.021 0.034
# [4,] 0.144 0.154 0.066 0.121 0.112 0.055 0.022 0.110 0.088 0.120
# [5,] 0.144 0.154 0.066 0.121 0.112 0.055 0.022 0.110 0.088 0.120
# [6,] 0.144 0.154 0.066 0.121 0.112 0.055 0.022 0.110 0.088 0.120

# grab the maximum prediction / label for each test image
max_pred <- max.col(pred) - 1

# look
table(max_pred, mnist$test$labels)
```

- Build dummy matrix and formula manually:

```
# create binary matrix representation manually
yd <- model.matrix(~ y -1, data=train)

# Build data.frame: first ten columns are the label matrix
d <- cbind.data.frame(yd, train[-1])

# Build formula
form <- reformulate(
             response=paste(names(d)[1:10], collapse="+"), # the ten column response
             termlabels=paste(names(d)[-(1:10)], collapse="+")) # the predictor pixels

set.seed(1)
mod <- neuralnet(form, data = d[1:100,], hidden = 2, 
                             act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE)

# Then predict as before
```